How to capture the output from a C library called from multiple threads in Rust?
For the past few days, I've searched for a way to capture the output of C libraries in Rust.
Here is the context:

I have a project at work in Rust that uses C libraries through FFI
The project is designed to run in a Unix-like OS
The project is build using the build.rs script that links the static libraries to the project
The projects spawns multiple threads to work
Those threads calls functions from the C libraries
The called functions from the C libraries print to STDOUT a progress and other messages

The libraries were used in building binaries that were later used in a project.
I would like to know if there is a way to capture in each thread the output from the called functions.
I consider that my problem is a generalized version of this question: Can stdout/stderr of a C/C++ library be caught by Rust?
What I have tried so far:

I've searched how to redirect the STDOUT in the Rust process and read it in a thread, but this works when there is only one work thread as far as I tested;
I've searched how to use the set_print from the Rust nightly build, but it captures only the messages printed with println!, not the messages from the FFI;


stdout is per-process, so you cannot redirect it for each thread differently.

just run it as a child process and parse its output in the parent process.

You could preload a library that redefines printf. Then, using thread-local storage, pass the output to your collecctor.

Probably you should be looking at whether there is a way to configure or modify the library so that it provides the wanted data via a mechanism other than writing to the standard output. Or perhaps at alternative libraries that could be used instead.  This might be a win in more ways than one, because for the most part, I don't take it as a sign of quality implementation that a library (as opposed to a program) writes to the standard output at all.  The issue you are now facing is among the reasons.

@JohnBollinger maybe you be right. I'll try to see how to edit those libraries to give the progress in another way. Or maybe I'll try to override the functionality of printf (Streve Ford's sugestion ), if possible. Thanks you all.

The libraries where used in building binaries that were later used by another project. We wanted to integrate everything in a single project.
@AhmedAEK maybe I wasn't clear about what I wanted to achieve, but now I think I explained it a little better.
